# Missing Controller in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have found the following error:

> Error: Controller could not be found. Error: Create the class
>   Controller below in file: app\Controller\Controller.php

```
<?php
class Controller extends AppController {

}
```

what I have to do to solve this problem,please suggest me

Comment: what is URL that you try to add?

Comment: I hope you have changed the names with example names? `AppController` already extends the core `Controller` class, so doing something like this is never going to work. Please use your real Controller names.

Comment: This is commonly the case if no route matches the request - what's in your routes file?

Comment: At the end of your routes.php file you should have the code `require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';`. That will load the CakePHP default routes and prevent this error.

Answer (score 2):

You got it all backwards.

Its

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
class AppController extends Controller {}
```

Comment: it may be that the code that is showed is part of the error message that cake generated. E.g. It's trying to construct an `[noname]Controller` and then outputs instructions on 'how' to create one. OP may make this clearer by adding additional information

Answer (score 0):

`Controller` class is already reserved for cakephp core library.

You can not use `controller` as class because `AppController` already extending `Controller` class of cakephp.